# Wrong bindind on select option ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, binding

When I post the form to the `Controller`, the binding on the `VehiclePlate` in `asp-for` gets the `value` of the select option (`@vehicle.Category`) but I want to get the `text` of the option (`@vehicle.Plate`) in the `Controller`. How can I do that?

This is my `select`:

```
@model Exam
...
<select asp-for="VehiclePlate" id="listVehicle" data-init-plugin="select2" style="width: 100%">
    @foreach (var vehicle in ViewBag.Vehicles)
    {
       <option value="@vehicle.Category">@vehicle.Plate</option>
    }
</select>
```

And this is my `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Exam exam)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The select tag has an asp-items attribute which you can set to a SelectList, e.g

```
<select asp-for="VehiclePlate" asp-items='new SelectList(ViewBag.Vehicles, "Plate", "Plate")'>
</select>
```

The "Plate", "Plate" part means, that the select uses Plate as value and as text for the dropdown.

Comment: Ok, but this do not answer the question.

Comment: Then I don't understand what your question is. You want to get the selected Plate in the controller? If so, then put it both as value and as text of the options.

Comment: I need the category in the View, that's why I'm using it in the value.But nevermind, already got it.